# Finding output of geoprocessing operation in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing

I am merging some features using the Geoprocessing Merge tool in ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop. The tool requires that the output is saved in a folder. Although this was done after the process ended successfully i could not locate the final output in the folder i saved it in. I have tried searching all the other folders but still cannot find it.

How do i locate the final output?

Comment: Did you run a single geoprocessing tool or a model?

Answer (score 3):

On the Geoprocessing menu, see the Results option. This will open a new window which lists the geoprocessing results from the Current Session.

Right-click on the top line of the results and choose Open - this will show you the parameters which were used in the geoprocessing session, including the location of the output data.

[image]

Comment: Ya, the results showed the process was successful, but i cannot locate the output in my folder. I tried to copy the output from the result but that didnt also work

Comment: In the screenshot above, I have the open to right-click then Open. This allows me to re-run the geoprocessing operation using the same parameters - you may be able to use this to re-create your output

Answer (score 1):

The default location for geoprocessing output in ArcGIS is in a geodatabase in your My Documents folder: `My Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb`

You can browse to this using ArcCatalog or Add Data in ArcMap.

If you have run the tool from within ArcMap it may even have added the output as a layer inside your current map.

Comment: Thanks but i checked the default geodatabase and there was nothing, in fact i checked almost all the other folders but still the same, i am going to try again today though.